# dbcontext does not contain a definition for 'Refresh'

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I'm working with the entity framework code first and am getting the following compilation error.
dbcontext does not contain a definition for 'Refresh'.  I have seen many examples where the Refresh method is being used.  But when i add the Refresh method to my dbcontext I get a complilation error.  I'm using the following namespaces.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Linq;
```

Am I missing one? I tried to look it up but did not find the namespace.

Comment: It's likely that any examples you've seen with `Refresh` are derived versions of `DbContext` - it'd help if you could post some code as to how you're using your context.

Comment: Does this help?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221314/refresh-entity-instance-with-dbcontext

Answer (score 30):

DbContext does indeed not have a Refresh() method.

The examples you saw were probably using [ObjectContext.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718.aspx).

You can get one from the other:

```
 db = new MyDbContext())
 ...   
 var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
 ctx.Refresh();
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5340990/60761) has more about the details and differences.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ-to-SQL has a confusingly similar [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) class, that has this method.

Entity Framework: does not.