# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) after context.refresh()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to `insert` by using EF and pasing all parameters but still for some reason I am getting `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.` error.

I looked into [Solution for: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819813/solution-for-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpected-n) and [dbcontext does not contain a definition for 'Refresh'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177718/dbcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-refresh) but still I am getting the error.

I tried following approaches:

```
foreach (var mainItemDeliveryTag in mainItemDeliveryTagList)
{
    try
    {   //Option-1
        var mainItemTag = DataContext.Set<MainItemDeliveryTag>();
        mainItemTag.Add(new MainItemDeliveryTag { MainItemID = mainItemId, DeliveryProviderTagID = mainItemDeliveryTag.DeliveryProviderTagID, IsDeliveryTagSelected = mainItemDeliveryTag.IsDeliveryTagSelected });

        //Option-2
        var mainItemDeliveryTagObj = new MainItemDeliveryTag()
        {
            MainItemID = mainItemId,
            DeliveryProviderTagID = mainItemDeliveryTag.DeliveryProviderTagID,
            IsDeliveryTagSelected = mainItemDeliveryTag.IsDeliveryTagSelected,
        };
        DataContext.MainItemDeliveryTag.Add(mainItemDeliveryTagObj);

        //Option-3
        DataContext.Entry(mainItemDeliveryTag).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
    {
        var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DataContext).ObjectContext;
        ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, mainItemDeliveryTag);
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: First of all: use Option-2 but move SaveChanges() invoke outside the loop. What is the mainItemId? Is it primary key for this table? Could tell us where you create your DataContext?

Comment: MainItemId is not primary key. It is just to associate some value with id

Comment: @MarcinIwanowski I didn't have any auto increment column in my table so EF was not able to do insert records. I added one column with auto increment and run the same code. It started working.

Answer (score 0):

Previously my table didn't have any column with auto increment value. I added new column with auto increment and now I am able to insert records.

Old Table Structure:

[image]

New Table Structure:

[image]