# How to update many-to-many relations from database in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What we have: MySQL, .NET Connector, C#, ADO Model with relations (many to many)

I have three tables: users, groups and usergroups
Another program add new items to users and usergroups tables, but then i try to get all users from any group i get no changes. I get changes only if i restart my program.
So my question is how to fix it? How to update related objects from database. Or is it possible to turn off caching?

Comment: show some code so we can work with something:)

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221314/refresh-entity-instance-with-dbcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you aren't getting any changes is that your DbContext isn't being updated when you do a pull for data, which *could* explain why it pulls changes only after your program restarts.

Comment: Yes, but... how to update it without restart? I can't track any changes that another program do.